# DocumentDB: The input Body length is invalid. Ensure to provide a script of size lesser than '102400' characters

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-sdk-.net

I'm getting the below error while trying to create a stored procedure using Azure documentDb .NET SDK. The script content size is 430KB.

> Message: {"Errors":["The input Body length is invalid. Ensure to provide a script of size lesser than '102400' characters.","The request payload is invalid. Ensure to provide a valid request payload."]}

I could see the below from [Azure DocumentDB limits](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/documentdb-limits/) article

> Maximum request size of stored procedure, trigger and UDF: 512KB

Could anyone please explain below.

1. Is this the stored procedure script body size?
2. If it is then what does this error mean?

Comment: I'm looking into this, but I gotta ask: How does one construct a 430K stored procedure???

Comment: @David: I meant the Javascript function body size which would be the stored procedure definition body in the DocumentDB

Comment: 430KB for a stored procedure is rather large. Did you know that the entire JSQuery (minified) is only 84KB.

Comment: When creating a stored procedure, it is a good idea to minify the script. You will be able to save a much bigger script if it has been minified.

Comment: @Ram if you would like to reach out to us to discuss this, and why you need such a large script, then please reach out to us via askdocdb.com

Comment: I've gotten into the habit of including underscore.js and async.js libraries as well as sql-from-mongo in my sprocs. It makes them pretty big but not 100KB big even with the core functionality of the sproc.

Comment: @Ryan: Thanks for the reply. Actually the script includes an external library as the inner function which is making it to that size even after minification. Ok I will give one more try to it and reach out to you if it's stay the same size.

Comment: @Larry: Could you please let me know what tool do you use to minify?

Comment: @Ram, I don't have to minify for any of my sprocs. Even with async.js, underscore.js, and sql-from-mongo, I'm under the limit. However, in the past, I have used uglify-js to minify code going to the browser. Now-a-days, I use webpack for my browser packages, but it's much more work to use and I don't know if it would be appropriate for minimizing a sproc. I use `documentdb-utils.loadSprocs()` to include underscore.js, async.js, and sql-from-mongo as well as modularized (required) code for a particular sproc.

Comment: This conversation is much better suited to chat. Lots of interesting information being discussed here. But it's now deviated from the core question, and the comments are not a substitute for a discussion forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this refers to the size of the script body. 
The max size for a stored procedure body is 100KB.

I will make a note to address the documentation accordingly.

Comment: Is there any difference between script body and stored procedure body. I believe they are same, isn't it. Do you mean the documentation is mentioning the stored procedure request/body size wrong?

Comment: stored procedure == script. so script body and stored procedure body are the same. I might've used the terms interchangeably. 

yes, I meant the documentation was wrong. it has been fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your help Ryan. But I hope to see this size to get better(an increment) in the near future to support larger scripts with dependencies like in my case.